# Visual Studio Code Python notebook output expansion?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to expand the cell of a large output for python notebooks (ipynb)? Similar to how it typically works in jupyter notebooks, where if you double click the output, it toggles between expansion and scrolling?

Answer (score 5):

No sorry that's not possible at the moment. Feel free to log a suggestion at
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues

Comment: Understood. Thank you!